# TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress executes on touch release?

Tags: react-native

Rather than the `onPress` event triggering when a touch is pressed onto the `TouchableWithoutFeedback` component, it is triggered when a touch is released. Is this how the onPress event is supposed to work..?

Is there an event for the actual touch press rather than the touch release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, triggering the `onPress` event on release is the intended behavior.

You can use [`onPressIn`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html#onpressin) if you want to trigger an action immediately when a button is clicked.

Comment: No problem! And yeah, it doesn't help that the docs are incomplete